# UK Keyboard Layout doesn't show up

Tags: keyboard-layout

I've the latest Ubuntu version working on my desktop. But when I go to `System -> Preference -> Keyboard -> Layout` and select English UK or any other country, I cannot see the keyboard layouts in the screen below.

I did a fresh install on my old laptop and I can clearly see the different layouts for different countries.

I believe there are some files missing that have the keymap data?? Can someone please help with how I can reinstall those needed files?

My current layout is English US but I need to change it to English UK

Tired of searching! Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Please try

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```